# CKEditor & jQuery - what am I doint wrong?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to replace textarea with CKEditor using jQuery and I must be doing something wrong. (with javascript it works fine).

Here is the code i am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $('#rfp_description').ckeditor();
    } );
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="rfp_description" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include jquery before ckeditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patsy Issa has solved my problem

> Include jquery before ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Check you file.js is in correct path and reorder the script tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $('#rfp_description').ckeditor();
    } );
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="rfp_description" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```